# Buenos días, como puedo desplegar y ocultar con un botón, todo el contenido de los accordion, por si quero ver todos desplegados en vez de 1 solo

Tags: html, accordion

**La pagina tiene un main que contiene diferentes secciones accordion. Lo que estoy intentando hacer y no consigo, es hacer un button o opción selecta(mostrar/ocultar. Para que al hacer click o elegir opción, se desplieguen todos los accordion a la vez y se oculten al cambiar de opción.**

He probado diferentes maneras, hacer acordions con id y una función que dependiendo de la id despliegue o oculte. Pero solo llegaba a desplegarse uno de todos los accordio. A ver si me podéis aconsejar algo que me sirva. Gracias, saludos.

```css
body {
    background-color: #c1b398;
}


header {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#605951;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; /* Radio de borde solo en la parte superior */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Aquí se define la sombra */
 
}

header p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 350px;
    font-family: Anton;
    font-size:60px;
    color: white;
    
}

menu {
    position: relative;
    top: -24px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fbeec2;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; /* Radio de borde solo en la parte superior */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Aquí se define la sombra */

}

menu ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
   
}

menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;

}

menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

menu a:hover{
    color: #61a6ab;
}


.contenido_links {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; /* Radio de borde solo en la parte superior */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Aquí se define la sombra */
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.titulo_content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 1150px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

.titulo_content h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-bottom: black 1px solid;
    
}

.acordiontodo {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.secciones_content {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;

}

.secciones_content h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;

    
}

.tabla-accesos {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .fila {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .celda {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
  }
  

  .celda a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  .celda a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }

footer {
    position: relative;
    top: -69px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #61a6ab;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Aquí se define la sombra */
}

footer ul{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;

}

footer li{
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;


}
.color1 { 
    background-color: #c1b398;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.color2 { 
    background-color:#605951;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    
}

.color3 { 
    background-color: #fbeec2;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.color4 { 
    background-color:  #61a6ab; 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.color5 { 
    background-color: #accec0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  
  .accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .active:after {
    content: "\2212";
  }
  
  .panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap">
    <title>ITHQ - Control Panel</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="contenido_links">
            <div class="titulo_content">
                <h1>Accesos</h1>
            </div>
            <section class="secciones_content">
                <button class="accordion">Iberostar</button>
                <div class="panel">
                    <section class="secciones_content">
                        <div class="tabla-accesos">
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a
                                        href="https://iberostar.app.businesscards.eco/dashboard/home?page=1"
                                        target="_blank">Business
                                        Card</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://ls.iberostar.com/login.aspx "
                                        target="_blank">LanSweeper</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="http://wifi-iberostar.hmobile.es:3000/admin/login_logs"
                                        target="_blank">Portal
                                        Wifi (GrupoIberostar) Sede Central </a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a
                                        href="https://grupoiberostar.ivsign.net/CertManager/Auth/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fCertManager%2fOrga%2fRule%2fRuleSet%3fruleid%3d3986%26delegid%3d5563&ruleid=3986&delegid=5563"
                                        target="_blank">Ivsing
                                        (Certificados)</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a
                                        href="https://iberostar.secretservercloud.eu/app/#/secrets/view/all"
                                        target="_blank">Acceso
                                        PAM</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://intranet.iberostar.com/inicioAppF12.aspx"
                                        target="_blank">Intranet</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a
                                        href="https://iberostar-949.vmwareidentity.de/catalog-portal/ui#/app-favorite"
                                        target="_blank">Work
                                        Space One - Sincronización usuarios</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://ar.iberostar.com/IBSAdmin" target="_blank">Active
                                        roles</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://172.25.102.2:8443/ccmadmin/showHome.do"
                                        target="_blank">Centralita
                                        Telefonia Cisco Sede Central</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://mas.service-now.com/serviceportal"
                                        target="_blank">Portal Soporte
                                        Dynatos (Readsoft)</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://monitor.ptmindra.net/login"
                                        target="_blank">Monitorización
                                        Grafana</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://cn1423.awmdm.com/AirWatch/#/Device/Dashboard"
                                        target="_blank">MDM</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://euce1-104.sentinelone.net/login"
                                        target="_blank">Sentinel One -
                                        Consola
                                        EDR</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://sharepoint.grupoiberostar.com/SitePages/Inicio.aspx"
                                        target="_blank">Sharepoint</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://app.vm.deloitte.es/" target="_blank">BugBlast</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="http://srcen103:8000/" target="_blank">Panel control HP</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://www.signaturit.com/" target="_blank">Signaturit</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://srcen112.ibs.loc/commandcenter/#/dashboard/commcell"
                                        target="_blank">CommVault -
                                        Gestión Backups</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="http://srcen56/reports/browse/" target="_blank">SCCM
                                        Report</a></div>
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://account.docusign.com/" target="_blank">Docusing</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fila">
                                <div class="celda"><a href="https://lastpass.com/?ac=1&lpnorefresh=1"
                                        target="_blank">Admin Lastpass</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <button class="accordion">CDN</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <section class="secciones_content">
                    <div class="tabla-accesos">
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://dash.cloudflare.com" target="_blank">CloudFlare</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://control.akamai.com" target="_blank">Akamai Control
                                    Center</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>

            <button class="accordion">Proofpoit</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <section class="secciones_content">
                    <div class="tabla-accesos">
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://threatinsight.proofpoint.com/auth/new"
                                    target="_blank">TAP
                                    Dashboard</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://admin.proofpoint.com/auth" target="_blank">Email
                                    Protection</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://00787901.pphosted.com:10000/admin" target="_blank">POD-
                                    Consola
                                    Admin central ProofPoint</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>

            <button class="accordion">Vodafone</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <section class="secciones_content">
                    <div class="tabla-accesos">
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://www.vodafone.es/c/particulares/es/"
                                    target="_blank">Vodafone</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-lAqMQMKOr_yV7_3AW749oGVTpVLJSVz?usp=drive_link"
                                    target="_blank">Documentos
                                    alta Vodafone</a></div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15qNpZ5vchsu2hKuKk8McbNxF-FyvdTIQYh27zENIi0E/edit#gid=1102419725"
                                    target="_blank">€
                                    Vodafone</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>

            <button class="accordion">Azure</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <section class="secciones_content">
                    <div class="tabla-accesos">
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://portal.azure.com/#home" target="_blank">Portal Azure</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>

            <button class="accordion">Otros</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <section class="secciones_content">
                    <div class="tabla-accesos">
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KAZvFEhehUUN5VJisQKyzTEDgtj3lH3hdDg0d4onuGU/edit#gid=940308788"
                                    target="_blank">Listado
                                    Servidore Azure, Central y Hoteles</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cIeYgwb1GZcrKnzSnWkVAcdZVNSeqikVLKEEV9Y5UVg/edit#gid=2014774093"
                                    target="_blank">Documento
                                    seguimiento entregas Dell</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tkNEQNTx-LVZWYrCPyg6nwYv-yZLHAzz47UW9qM1lFg/edit#gid=1691443906"
                                    target="_blank">Cisco
                                    Jabber Sede Central -Entrega Cascos</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BVQHIClL1qwl3S_xotqgQOsxTix48FpHpf03nDyygh4/edit#gid=1854216301"
                                    target="_blank">Hoja
                                    Gestión DNS e inventario Dominios web</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ODASpmrWVNIg90xobzqEzVucl4k-jo5iwHmWFpmU4M0/edit#gid=0"
                                    target="_blank">Listado
                                    VLAN's Sede</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a href="https://www.aireasensor.com/" target="_blank">Sensor CO2</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://login.pyracloud.com/u/login/identifier?state=hKFo2SAwZVBTZGV0amZNeUNHU3QySFNNbDRtQ24zWXg4SXpDQaFur3VuaXZlcnNhbC1sb2dpbqN0aWTZIHVraHluek80MGdIVlgzU2lBbk50dW9MTEw0SDZUM2sxo2NpZNkgcVB1YUN5NHNNc0hVRVVBZXl0NE5GWDcyZXJMY3NoMXk"
                                    target="_blank">Pyracloud</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AfAroqLhSCwV97HdjLHn4hyJpBr1QL1uWZD91hbcmw/edit#gid=0"
                                    target="_blank">Control
                                    print corners</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fila">
                            <div class="celda"><a
                                    href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-kQNfnYZm1Kw7v-Rj5_On7GsYTiGZCopT_kkmcM85eI/edit#gid=0"
                                    target="_blank">Extensiones
                                    CC</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="celda"><a href="http://srcen56/Reports/browse/" target="_blank">Consola report
                                    SCCM</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        </section>
        </div>

        <script>
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                    } else {
                        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes intentar es lo siguiente. Puedes utilizar una clase adicional para controlar el estado de visibilidad de los paneles.

De esta forma

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                panel.classList.toggle("show");
                
                // Oculta los paneles que no están siendo clicados
                for (var j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
                    if (acc[j] !== this) {
                        acc[j].classList.remove("active");
                        acc[j].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Se agrega la clase "show" al panel cuando se hace clic en el botón correspondiente.
Se recorre el array de accordions y se asegura de que solo el panel del botón clicado tenga la clase "show".
Se eliminan las clases "active" y "show" de los demás accordions para ocultar sus paneles.

Espero te sirva, saludos!